# Acknowledge a message from a different Channel/Session in JMS

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, activemq-classic

I need a message to be Acknowledged in a different Session than the one it is created in. If the consumed message is not ACKed in a given time, it should be added back to the queue. Is this possible using JMS( planning to use ActiveMQ as the broker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible.

If the message is consumed, **it should be acknowledged by the consumer session** (it can be auto or client acknowledgement). Acknowledgment is the key for guaranteed messaging and transaction mechanism. JMS server ensures the message is sent/consumed successfully using acknowledgement.

Regarding timeout question, **if the JMS server didn't receive the ack in given time period, the message will be redelivered usually with `JMSRedelivered` flag set.** I don't think it will be added back to the Queue then able to be consumed by same session or another session as a new message.